# Error "Could not resolve the assembly "Mono.Android"" after moved project to Mac (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Recently, i clone my Xamarin.Forms project from my old windows laptop to my new mac laptop.

However, after running this project i get an error **"Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Mono.Android". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. if this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors."**

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Create a new project. Are you able to get that running on the mac's android emulator? (following instructions in Microsoft's docs for doing so)

Comment: To re-reference an assembly, you can right click on the assembly giving the warning and delete it, then right click on the dependencies, and click `add reference`. Then browse to the relevant `Mono.Android.dll`, and add it.